# where does kafka save the local state store?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I created a Kafka topic and sent some messages to it.
I created an application which had the stream topology. Basically, it was doing the sum and materialized it to a local state store.
I saw the new directory was created in the state folder I configured.
I could read the sum from the local state store.
Everything was good so far.
Then, I turned off my application which was running the stream.
I removed the directory created in my state folder.
I restart the Kafka cluster.
I restart my application which has the stream topology.
In my understanding, the state was gone. Kafka needs to do the aggregation again. But it did not. I was still able to get the previous sum result.
How comes? Where did Kafka save the local state store?

Here is my code

```
Reducer<Double> reduceFunction = (subtotal, amount) -> {
    // detect when the reducer is triggered
    System.out.println("reducer is running to add subtotal with amount..." + amount);
    return subtotal + amount;
};
groupedByAccount.reduce(reduceFunction,
                Materialized.<String, Double, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(BALANCE).withValueSerde(Serdes.Double()));
```

I explicitly put the System.out in the reduceFunction. Whenever it is executed, I shall see it on the console.
But I did not see any after restart kafka cluster and my application.
Does Kafka really recover the state? Or it saves state somewhere else?

Comment: relevant - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Internal+Data+Management

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken and according to **Designing Event-Driven Systems** by Ben Stopford (free book) on page 137, it states:

> We could store, these
> stats in a state store and they’ll be saved locally as well as being backed up to
> Kafka, using what’s called a changelog topic, inheriting all of Kafka’s durability
> guarantees.

It seems like a copy of your state store is also backed up in Kafka itself (i.e. changelog topic). I don't think restarting a cluster will flush out (or remove) messages already in a topic as they're kept track in the Zookeeper.
So once you restart your cluster and application again, the local state store is recovered from Kafka.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But if the local state is saved on kafka cluster as well, I can get that state from any machine, right? Why there is remote state store and using RPC to get the remote state? like this https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app

Comment: This is to support the eventual synchrony between the local state store and Kafka. Once the state stores are synchronized, then they live in Kafka at that point. This supports my statement about the state store living in Kafka (after this synchronization occurs).

Comment: If the volume of the data is huge (lets say in TBs), then how the local store gets updated? How does local store gets the data from remote store/changelog topic?